# warning related to package-json folder

Tags: javascript, json

everytime i write code of solidity in vs code it shows schema warning..
it is saying ("Problems loading reference 'vscode://schemas/settings/configurationDefaults': Unable to load schema from 'vscode://schemas/settings/configurationDefaults': cannot open vscode://schemas/settings/configurationDefaults. Detail: Unable to resolve text model content for resource vscode://schemas/settings/configurationDefaults.")

i have tried this:"git.ignoreLimitWarning": true,but it is not resolving.